# Error creating files. Unexpected or unknown element or attribute in the application descriptor file. Flash cc - air - xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to add some images(icons) in my .ipa file by editing XML manually.

I know I should edit XML, make it read-only then publish the ipa from Flash.

But everytime, Flash says:

```
Error creating files . 
Unexpected or unknown element or attribute in the application descriptor file.
application.icon.image30*29 is an unexpected element/attribute"
image30*29 is a sample .
```

This my XML:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!-- 
 Usage:

 To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.
 <description>
 <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
 <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
 <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
 </description>

 To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.
 <name>
 <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
 <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
 <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
 </name>
-->
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">
  <id>air.SIRTET</id>
  <versionNumber>0.3.7</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel/>
  <filename>SIRTET</filename>
  <description/>
  <name>SIRTET</name>
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>sirtetmobile.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>cpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon>
    
    <image48x48>AppIconsForPublish/logo48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>AppIconsForPublish/logo72.png</image72x72>
    <image57x57>logo57.png</image57x57>
    <image114x114>logo114.png</image114x114>
    <image512x512>logo512.png</image512x512>
    <image50x50>logo50.png</image50x50>
    <image58x58>logo58.png</image58x58>
    <image100x100>logo100.png</image100x100>
    <image144x144>logo144.png</image144x144>
    <image1024x1024>logo1024.png</image1024x1024>
    <image29x29>logo29.png</image29x29>
 <image30x29>logo29.png</image30x29>
   
 </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
 </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
  <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
  <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says it all, `<image30x29>logo29.png</image30x29>` is not valid. 30px by 29px is not an acceptable aspect ratio for an icon, all icons have to be square.

To quote the [Adobe AIR documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-6fd06f0f1293d3b33ea-7ffc):

---

**imageNxN**

Defines the path to an icon relative to the application directory.

The following icon images can be used, each specifying a different icon size:

- image16x16
- image29x29 (AIR 2+)
- image32x32
- image36x36 (AIR 2.5+)
- image48x48
- image50x50 (AIR 3.4+)
- image57x57 (AIR 2+)
- image58x58 (AIR 3.4+)
- image72x72 (AIR 2+)
- image100x100 (AIR 3.4+)
- image114x114 (AIR 2.6+)
- image128x128
- image144x144 (AIR 3.4+)
- image512x512 (AIR 2+)
- image1024x1024 (AIR 3.4+)

The icon must be a PNG graphic that is exactly the size indicated by the image element. Icon files must be included in the application package; icons referenced in the application descriptor document are not included automatically.

Comment: I have to add a 640*1136 icon for iPhone5 and it's normal! That's not true. It's not about acceptable aspect. even by 31*31 - 59*59- 95*95!

Comment: Sorry but according to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-6fd06f0f1293d3b33ea-7ffc) such ratios do not exist. Even if they are acceptable, it doesn't change the fact that the error message is telling you that 30x29 is not acceptable

Comment: But people are using this method to add 640*1136 icon for iPhone 5 as people asked.
I tried to add another standard image 16*16 manually. It doesn't work and I faced on the same error.
My Flash doesn't accept any changes in XML

Comment: Two things: 1. your error is regarding 30x29 not 640x1136. 2. 640x1136 is the iPhone 5 [Launch Image](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000) requirement, not an application icon, these are two different things

Comment: 30*29 was an example. instead of 30*29 I used different sizes to test this bug.
Your ipa has to have a 640*1136 icon to be approved by apple.

Comment: No you need a 640x1136 Launch Image to be approved by apple, this is different to application icons as the link in my previous comment spells out. Also since your not trying to use 30x29 could you please include in your question the actual XML and error your trying to fix.

Comment: Thank you so muck. Solved. I thought I should add this icon as an icon.